# Как докачать расширения в Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, расширения

При первом запуске Android Studio возникает окно, с помощью которого можно установить все необходимые расширения, но после создания первого проекта, это окно больше не появляется, но бывают случаи, когда нужно то, что не скачал раньше, как докачать расширения в этом случае?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#sdk-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Это называется Android SDK, вам нужно перейти на вторую вкладку: SDK Tools]

Попадаем сюда вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или как видно на первом изображении через настройки.

Comment: Большое спасибо!